# Getting button presses on Windows Mobile 6

Tags: windows-mobile, button, windows-mobile-6

I am making an application for a windows mobile smartphone, and I would like to know, using C# and the Windows Mobile 6 SDK, how can I make a window that can get input events even after minimized? Is it possible? I'm sure it is.

Please let me know,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is not possible, unless you are working directly with OEM (in which case you have an opportunity to modify the system itself up to some extent). So, if you are looking for a general approach, you will not find it.

However, if you are targeting some specific WM6 device, you can try to see if:

a) Windows hooks are still enabled and not used by some system service (note that Windows hooks are officially disabled on mobile editions, they are officially disabled even for WM5, but that's not really the case for all the phones)

b) OEM has provided its own proprietary notification system (sometimes they do, this is quite tricky to catch, and if you do not know someone who already know the details, it is very difficult to do it).

To sum up, you can not write a solution that will work on every WM6 device, and there are security issues (e.g. stealing passwords, etc) that make this decision reasonable.

Comment: For Windows Mobile Professional the Window hooks,work fine. Lots of p/invoke

But for Windows Mobile Standard, it will totally depend on the security from the manufacturer